# Grails gorm criteria for longitude, latitude and distance

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, grails-orm, criteria

I need the people of a given Person ordered by their distance. The person table has the address of each person and longitude and latitude fields.  I tried withCriteria and createCriteria with no luck.

The following query works by it returns people with in a distance value.

```
def query = "from Person as person where SQRT(POW((69.1 * (latitude - ${myPersonLat})) , 2 ) + POW((53 * (longitude - ${myPersonLng})), 2)) < 30"
def results = Person.executeQuery(query)
```

Instead of that, i need to get all the people from db ordered by the distance.

Any help with creating the GORM Criteria is greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm not sure on the exact syntax, but you could try something like:

```
String query = """
from Person as person 
where SQRT(POW((69.1 * (latitude - ${myPersonLat})) , 2 ) + POW((53 * (longitude - ${myPersonLng})), 2)) < 30
order by (POW((69.1 * (latitude - ${myPersonLat})) , 2 ) + POW((53 * (longitude - ${myPersonLng})), 2))
"""
```

Alternatively, you can name the subquery in a select/join and then use it in both places above, to reduce some code duplication.  Unfortunately I'm away from my dev machine, so I can't test it out.  [This](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html) HQL doc may be helpful though.